# Multiple routing urls for single service AngularJS

Tags: rest, angularjs

I have multiple URL paths that I would like to map to a single resource. However I am unsure how to change the URL based on the function called.  For example the :dest mapping for query would be /allProducts, however destroy would be something along the lines of /delete/:id

```
service.factory('ProductsRest', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('service/products/:dest', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true },
        save: {method: 'POST'},
        show: { method: 'GET'},
        edit: { method: 'GET'},
        update: { method: 'PUT'},
        destroy: { method: 'DELETE' }
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For each action you can override the url argument.
Specially for this is the `url: {...}` argument.

**In your example:**

```
service.factory('ProductsRest', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('service/products/', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true },
        save: {method: 'POST', url: 'service/products/modifyProduct'},
        update: { method: 'PUT', url: 'service/products/modifyProduct'}
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 18):

I just needed to put the url in as the param.

```
service.factory('ProductsRest', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('service/products/:dest', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', params: {dest:"allProducts"}, isArray: true },
        save: {method: 'POST', params: {dest:"modifyProduct"}},
        update: { method: 'POST', params: {dest:"modifyProduct"}},
    });
}]);
```

Comment: how did you call each of these ? suppose you just wanted to call the save, did you do ProductsRest.save(); ?

Comment: nice solution but would prefer mikemueller solution, for some cases, its more clearly and readable.